# QTableWidget omits some itmes, items are created but ignored

Tags: c++, qt, missing-data, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have two different projects where I use `QTableWidget` object and I have the same issue in the both.
I try to fill the `QTableWidget` object with `new QTableWidgetItem` but some of items are missed, they are not represented in the table.
The problem appears with MinGW and MSVC compilers.
I've tried it with 5.12.1 and 5.12.5 Qt versions.
Please help me to figure what is wrong with it out.

I use very simple code like below
In one project if I call `createItems()` twice in a row so the table is filled
but the other project uses greater table so this code works if I call it much more times, but not fully anyway

```
void MainWindow::createItems()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); ++c)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem *pi = ui->tableWidget->item(r, c);
            if (pi != nullptr) continue;
            pi = new QTableWidgetItem();
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(r, c, pi);
            qDebug() << r << c << pi << ui->tableWidget->item(r, c)
                     << (pi == ui->tableWidget->item(r, c));
        }
    }
}
```

it's a part of qDebug output

```
0 0 0x2c4af2f0 0x2c4af2f0 true
0 1 0x2c4af970 0x2c4af970 true
0 2 0x2c4af9b0 0x2c4af9b0 true
0 3 0x2c4afa70 0x2c4afa70 true
0 4 0x2c4aeb30 0x2c4aeb30 true
0 5 0x2c4aecb0 0x2c4aecb0 true
1 0 0x2c4aed30 0x2c4aed30 true
1 1 0x2c4aedf0 0x2c4aedf0 true
1 2 0x2c4aee30 0x2c4af9b0 false
2 0 0x2c4afdf0 0x2c4afdf0 true
2 1 0x2c4aeef0 0x2c4aeef0 true
2 2 0x2c4aef30 0x2c4af9b0 false
```

please pay attention to (1, 2) and (0, 2) and (2, 2), why it happens?

and then I fill items in a cycle like below. Code is crashed when not all of the items are created, it's obvious that item pointer is null but I'm sure that it's been created

```
for (int r = 0; r < rows_amount; ++r)
{
    ui->tableWidget->item(r, 0)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, r);
    ui->tableWidget->item(r, 1)->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, r+1);
}
```

in the second project I fill items when they are created by 'new' command, then I call something like `pTable->setItem(r, c, pItem)`

In the second project where `setItem` is used, the table looks like [this (my real example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acISd.png)

It works normally on some computers, and the code is simple so I don't have any idea what I'm doing wrongly

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Item pointer is not null!
Can you check if it goes inside the if condition?

You should probably delete and null them is those cases.

Comment: Actually you are right and "(pi != nullptr)" condition is correct for some items, but it's strange to me anyway, the table is created from scratch and there shouldn't be any item. Also I tried to remove pointer checking and it means that all items should be replaced anyway, BUT I see it again "1 2 0x2c546b80 0x2c546540 false", some pointers has the same address. I see it at the same cells every time: (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2) and so on

Comment: I believe there's no guarantee in cpp (although it depends on compiler) but mostly you have to check every dynamic variable you created